# How to run fsck on guest VMs from KVM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I have a KVM server and one of my guest machine is crashed and prompting form fsck check. 
Now I dont have console access or dont have the root access of the guest VM.

Is there any way that I can run the fsck from the hypervisor ?

I use centos 6.1 as my hypervisor

Answer (score 15):

install libguestfs:

```
# yum install libguestfs-tools
```

use guestfish to open the disk image:

```
# guestfish -a /path/to/diskimage.img

Welcome to guestfish, the libguestfs filesystem interactive shell for
editing virtual machine filesystems.

Type: 'help' for help on commands
      'man' to read the manual
      'quit' to quit the shell   
<fs> run
<fs> list-filesystems
/dev/vda1: ext4
/dev/system/lv_root: ext4
/dev/system/lv_swap: swap
```

and fsck the problematic filesystem:

```
<fs> fsck /dev/system/lv_root
fsck should have 2 parameter(s)
type 'help fsck' for help on fsck
<fs> fsck  ext4 /dev/system/lv_root
...
```

good luck!

Comment: +1 looks like an interesting set of tools to try out

Comment: Broken in debian7 for me.

Comment: This looked promising, but unfortunately I get the following error at the time I type "run": `libguestfs: error: /usr/bin/supermin exited with error status 1.`. This is happening using Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: when I typed "run" I got the error "libvirt: XML-RPC error : Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': No such file or directory..." but that was fixed by finding that libvirtd was not running. After "systemctl start libvirtd" it worked. Thanks @mrc

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to mount the file on the loopback interface and fsck it. From the site [www.ingent.net/en/tag/kvm/](http://www.ingent.net/en/tag/kvm/) , use:

```
losetup -f
/dev/loop0
```

...to see that loop0 here is the next free device, then assign the disk image to that point.

```
losetup /dev/loop0 disk.raw
```

kpartx is used to create devices to access it.

```
kpartx -av /dev/loop0
```

Then you should be able to use fsck.

```
fsck.ext3 -f /dev/mapper/loop0p1
fsck.ext3 -f /dev/mapper/loop0p2
```

...and so on. The page is about converting systems to run on KVM, but this part cited above may put you on track to do an fsck repair; I'd add the caution that you should do this with a *copy* of your image file instead of the base image file, just in case something goes wrong.

Comment: This will only work on raw images, not qcow2

Comment: Long shot, the image could be converted to raw, fsck'd, then converted back. Roundabout, but could work.

Comment: might take days, if the image is large and/or is on a slow lun

Comment: *shrug* if it works when other options fail...it's still something that could be tried.

Comment: to complete the answer: when finished with repairing, the partition mapping and loop device can be removed like this: `sync; kpartx -dv /dev/loop0; losetup -d /dev/loop0`

Answer (score 1):

Besides what Bart Silverstrim suggested, I can see two ways:

1. use libguestfs to mount and manipulate the images
2. boot the VM with a liveCD ISO attached, and either reset the fsck flag or run it using the liveCD